# How to make a web service implement a library based interface?

Tags: spring, interface, jax-ws

In a project I am working on we have several servlets that all use a common API (developed by us) for database access among other things. The idea is to gradually take this functionality out from the shared jar file and place it in a JAX-WS web service for external applications to use. However, I have now hit a wall as we use spring to initialise our servlets and there is a type mismatch between the interface defined in the jar and the class generated by the web service even though they have the same package and name.

Upon further inspection it appears that a few things happen that I can see getting in the way:

1. The generated source from the web service contains its own version of the interface
2. The generated source for the implementation never actually implements the interface, it merely returns an object of the interface's type on request

   - This method isn't static though which I can imagine will create problems
3. I do remember reading that JAX-B can't actually handle interfaces, but this I discovered while creating the methods so may not apply to this section

With this in mind it seems I need to construct a bean in spring by calling the generated web service method but I can't figure out how. Any other suggestions are more than welcome as removing the interface is undesirable for testing / extensibility and the only other solution I can think of is to assign this class in the constructor rather than spring.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to extract the implementing object through the request. By using a [MethodInvokingFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html) you can set up an instance and store the result for use like any normal bean.

Example:

```
<bean id="implementingObject" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" autowire="byName">
    <property name="targetClass">
        <value>JAXWSServiceClass</value>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>getInterfacePortObject</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other bean is not annotated with `@Primary` annoted yours with `@Primary`

> Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency. If exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the autowired value. This annotation is semantically equivalent to the  element's primary attribute in Spring XML.
>
> May be used on any class directly or indirectly annotated with @Component or on methods annotated with @Bean.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html